# how to find daily visitors of website using php

Tags: php

i want to know that how to find approximate visitors and daily earning of website using php.

```
$value=$alexa.".".$random_number;
```

my current algorithm is using alexa and one random number .

so any idea what could be best algorithm and possible factors that effect it.

Comment: Why don't you use Google Analytics?

Comment: Google Analytics would work? not php though :-/

Comment: it has a api you can query with php :-)

Comment: never though about that. Good catch :-)

Comment: ya i think so google anaylytic API ... 50,000 request limit per day enough :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever somebody accesses your website, you could save the current timestamp and involved IP in a MySQL database table. When you want to get the number of visitors, you can just count every entry in the table, or count every entry in the table from a specific day, week, etc.

I would, however, say that using something like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) (it's free) is way easier and will give you a lot more detailed information and spare your server from extra work.

Comment: i want to find others websites visitors not mine :) check my site www.w3db.org    .. i want to add new feature which have ability to find approximate visitors of the site which is searched .

Comment: Only if you trust Google enough. Suggestion: Check out analytics alternatives as well (open source).

Answer (score 1):

You could always use google anyalytics, but if you want strictly PHP you can just use a simple database in a .txt file to count. Make a file called counter.txt and CHMOD to 777 if you're doing it on a webserver.

```
<?php
//Open the file and get it's contents
$readhandle = fopen('counter.txt', 'r');
$readfile = fread($readhandle, filesize('counter.txt'));
fclose($readhandle);

//Overwrite the file with the contents of it's earlier version + 1
$writehandle = fopen('counter.txt', 'w');
fwrite($writehandle, $readfile + 1);
fclose($writehandle);
?>
```

You could monitor this by looking into time functions with php, maybe make a new file with the date as the name every day.